# KnockoutJS mapping from JS not create an observable array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I thought the mapping plugin should return an observable array but the obbservable array is empty even though 'resp' response from server has 1000s of elements.

Am I missing something here?  Please see below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">         

        function tasksViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.tasks = ko.observableArray(null);

            self.load = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/benchmark',              
                    success: function(resp) {
                       // This line isn't working!
                       self.tasks = ko.mapping.fromJS(resp);
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            }
        }

        var viewModel = new tasksViewModel();

        $(function () {

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            viewModel.load();
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.tasks(resp);
```

you should set new value to existed observable array

Comment: Yes, I remember now. The mapping creates observables of single properties not arrays, thanks. Wish this was a little more clear on their site.